# Only allow update to another schema within a trigger

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, triggers, database-permissions

I'm using Oracle 11gR2, and I have two schemas -- `A` and `B`, and each has a similar `CUSTOMER` table.

When `B.CUSTOMER` is updated, I want the same updates to happen to `A.CUSTOMER`.  Schema A has full privileges to schema B, but I want schema B to have as few privileges on schema A as possible.

I wrote a procedure in schema A, `A.UPDATE_CUSTOMER` that takes a `B.CUSTOMER%ROWTYPE` variable and uses it to update A.CUSTOMER, and granted execute on the procedure to schema B.

I created a for each row after update trigger on `B.CUSTOMER` that calls this update procedure, and it works as desired.  But I'm thinking that user B could explicitly call the procedure outside of the trigger, and I don't want to allow this.

Is there a way to prevent `A.UPDATE_CUSTOMER` from being called by B outside of the trigger?  Or is there some other way to prevent user B from updating `A.CUSTOMER` outside of the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

The only natural way I can think of doing this is to disallow "create session" for B, and having all changes to B's schema made by user C who is granted the required privileges to do so. C would not of course have the privilege on A's schema.

I believe that triggers are implicitly [authid definer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#autoId44), but if not the trigger could call a procedure that is.